# An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. VS2022 Service-based database

Tags: sql, database, windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2022

In visual basic WFA, when I try to add a Service-based database to the project, it gives me "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format":
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIfS5.png)

[Service-based database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gncSF.png)

I tried enabling 32 bit applications with IIS, installing VS2022 preview.
I think I have the right packages as I have the database packages and .Net development components.

Note: I am running windows 11 Arm64 on parallels desktop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please dont upload text, error or code in images. Welcome to S.O. Please read the tutorial

Comment: Are you running the VS preview because the release version doesn't support ARM? I believe that support is fairly new but I'm not sure how new. It may be that LocalDB is not supported yet. It sounds like VS is trying to load something that is not compatible with ARM and, if you're adding an MDF data file to your project, that would likely be LocalDB. Are you able to connect to a SQL Server instance instead?

Comment: @jmcilhinney The normal version of VS didn't work and I thought VS preview might have fixed it. Also I can add a dataset(it is just the Service that is the issue), so I don't think it is localDB. When I tried to load a preexisting .MDF file it gives me the same error. I enabled the 32-bit applications with IIS(I was able to run a 32 bit x86 app).

Comment: Creating a typed `DataSet` doesn't require LocalDB, so that's pretty irrelevant. A service-based database is a SQL Server MDF file. The service it's based on is SQL Server. I'm not sure that IIS is relevant at all because it's talking about a Windows service, not a web service. A SQL Server instance is basically a Windows service. In order to create an MDF file, a LocalDB instance must be started and I believe that that is what is causing the issue. I could be wrong but the symptoms you describe support it. That's what you should investigate.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry for repeatedly asking you questions. I tried starting a LocalDB instance by using: `sqllocaldb start` and it didn't work. Is this the right way of starting a LocalDB, I tried google and this was the only way I could find

Comment: You're getting away from the topic of this question. I don't know for sure but I don't think LocalDB is supported on ARM. If you can't start an instance then that supports the theory but this question is not about how to start an instance of LocalDB. I don't think what you're doing would work anyway but I'm not sure. I'd start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver16) and that's all I have to say on that.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1441) is relevant, although it's a little old now.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I fixed the issue by using VS2017 instead(Because VS2017 doesn't have an Arm64 version I'm just using an emulated version, which doesn't have the error). Thank you so much for the help! And I don't think it would be possible for me to get the VS2022 server database working as the Microsoft developers would need to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue:
Visual Studio Arm64 edition has issue with database apparently. So I just used Visual studio 2017(Which has to be emulated on Arm64 devices) which just fixed it.